# Android show user yes-no dialog from background app or service

Tags: android, service, background, dialog

i want to pop-up a dialog while some specific event occurs. Say i am an antivirus and found a virus, i can't send notification for this right, user could be compromised even dead until he checks the notification.

So i want to show a dialog like allow-deny, or yes-no, not to disturb user, it's gonna happen very rarely.

So is there any way that a service or application shows a dialog while user is using another application, even playing a game.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `Notification` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html). I don't believe you can/should create an `AlertDialog` when its not in the foreground. See [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) for Android's information on design patterns regarding when you should and shouldn't use them (you're interested in the last paragraph.

To quote the documentation.

> **Dialogs and toasts are for feedback not notification**
>
> Your app should not create a dialog or toast if it is not currently on screen. Dialogs and Toasts should only be displayed as the immediate response to the user taking an action inside of your app. For further guidance on the use of dialogs and toasts, refer to Confirming & Acknowledging.

This is a better, less intrusive way of notifying the user in your specific case. I also know that its possible to create a notification from a background service.

You create the `Notification` using the `Notification.Builder` class, setting things like title, icon, text, when to display it and also the intent to launch when the user clicks on the notification (used to open your app at a desired location). Once created you then use the `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification)`. You specify an id so you can access the notification later.

Comment: Are these notifications small icons top of the screen? If so, what if user doesn't notice it, or dont bother to click, this is some kind of security program...

Comment: See above for more information regarding when to use notifications.

Comment: Thanks dude, i think im gonna have to use notification, i know this is not the place but, how about i become the foreground app while some event occurs, is that possible?

Comment: As in you force your app to come to foreground? I don't believe that is possible. The best way to do that is by supplying an intent with the notification so that it opens your app when the user touches it